# Avoiding atan2 in calculating angles - atan2 precision

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, math, geometry

we, developers very often need to calculate angle to perform rotation. Usually we can use atan2() function but sometimes we need more precision. What do you do then?

I know that theoretically atan2 is precise but in my system (iOS) it's inaccurate about 0.05 radians so it's big difference. That's not just my problem. I've seen similar opinions.

Comment: You need more precision than 1E-15 radians? Really?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CGAffineTranformRotate atan2 inaccuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766128/cgaffinetranformrotate-atan2-inaccuration)

Comment: No, it's not duplicate. It's general question about atan2 issues regarding iOS and maybe other systems. And here I'm not asking for solution for problem listed above (since I've solved it differently), I'm asking just in order to get to know. I think other developers sometimes have similar difficultes so it's kind of general question.

Comment: If you have a reproducible example of `atan2` producing an incorrect answer, on any platform, file a bug with the platform vendor.  Always.  bugreport.apple.com in this case.

Comment: If you're going to make the (ridiculous-sounding) claim that atan2 has an error of +/-0.05, you should give some specific examples of input values that produce such large errors.

Answer (score 3):

`atan2` is used to get an angle `a` from a vector `(x,y)`. If then you use this angle to apply a rotation you will use `cos(a)` and `sin(a)`.  You could simply compute cos and sin by normalizing (x,y), and keep them instead of the angle.  Precision will be higher, and you will save a lot of cycles lost in trigonometric functions.

Edit. If you really want an angle from (x,y), it can be computed using variants of [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) to the precision you need.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `atan2l` if `long double` has more precision than `double` in your system.

```
long double atan2l(long double y, long double x);
```

Comment: On the current ARM iOS devices, `long double` is just mapped to `double`, so you don't gain any precision using this. You will get extra precision in the iOS Simulator, because it runs on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, I've found that the standard trigonometry operators are precise to roughly 13 or 14 decimal digits, so it sounds very odd that you're seeing errors on the order of 0.05 radians. If you can produce code and specific values that demonstrate this, please [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com) on the behavior (and post the code here so that we can have a record of it).

That said, if you really need high precision for your trigonometry operators, I've modified a few of the routines that Dave DeLong created for his [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) code. These routines use NSDecimal for performing the math, giving you up to ~34 digits of decimal precision while avoiding your standard floating point problems with representing base 10 decimals. You can download the code for these modified routines from [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/FixedDDDecimalFunctions.zip).

An NSDecimal version of `atan()` is calculated using the following code:

```
NSDecimal DDDecimalAtan(NSDecimal x) {
    // from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series

    // The normal infinite series diverges if x > 1
    NSDecimal one = DDDecimalOne();
    NSDecimal absX = DDDecimalAbsoluteValue(x);

    NSDecimal z = x;
    if (NSDecimalCompare(&one, &absX) == NSOrderedAscending) 
    {
        // y = x / (1 + sqrt(1+x^2))
        // Atan(x) = 2*Atan(y)
        // From: http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/math/14680/faster-Taylor-s-series-of-Atan-x

        NSDecimal interiorOfRoot;
        NSDecimalMultiply(&interiorOfRoot, &x, &x, NSRoundBankers);
        NSDecimalAdd(&interiorOfRoot, &one, &interiorOfRoot, NSRoundBankers);
        NSDecimal denominator = DDDecimalSqrt(interiorOfRoot);
        NSDecimalAdd(&denominator, &one, &denominator, NSRoundBankers);
        NSDecimal y;
        NSDecimalDivide(&y, &x, &denominator, NSRoundBankers);

        NSDecimalMultiply(&interiorOfRoot, &y, &y, NSRoundBankers);
        NSDecimalAdd(&interiorOfRoot, &one, &interiorOfRoot, NSRoundBankers);
        denominator = DDDecimalSqrt(interiorOfRoot);
        NSDecimalAdd(&denominator, &one, &denominator, NSRoundBankers);
        NSDecimal y2;
        NSDecimalDivide(&y2, &y, &denominator, NSRoundBankers);

//        NSDecimal two = DDDecimalTwo();
        NSDecimal four = DDDecimalFromInteger(4);
        NSDecimal firstArctangent = DDDecimalAtan(y2);

        NSDecimalMultiply(&z, &four, &firstArctangent, NSRoundBankers);
    }
    else
    {
        BOOL shouldSubtract = YES;
        for (NSInteger n = 3; n < 150; n += 2) {
            NSDecimal numerator;
            if (NSDecimalPower(&numerator, &x, n, NSRoundBankers) == NSCalculationUnderflow)
            {
                numerator = DDDecimalZero();
                n = 150;
            }

            NSDecimal denominator = DDDecimalFromInteger(n);

            NSDecimal term;
            if (NSDecimalDivide(&term, &numerator, &denominator, NSRoundBankers) == NSCalculationUnderflow)
            {
                term = DDDecimalZero();
                n = 150;
            }

            if (shouldSubtract) {
                NSDecimalSubtract(&z, &z, &term, NSRoundBankers);
            } else {
                NSDecimalAdd(&z, &z, &term, NSRoundBankers);
            }

            shouldSubtract = !shouldSubtract;
        }
    }

    return z;
}
```

This uses a Taylor series approximation, with some shortcuts to speed convergence. I believe that the precision might not be the full 34 digits at results very close to Pi / 4 radians, so I might still need to fix that.

If you need extreme precision this is an option, but again what you're reporting shouldn't be happening with `double` values, so there's something odd here.

Answer (score 2):

Use angles very often? No, you don't. Out of 10 times that I have seen a developer use angles, 7 times he should have used linear algebra instead and avoid any trigoniometric functions.

A rotation is better done with a matrix, not with an angle. See also this question:

[CGAffineTranformRotate atan2 inaccuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766128/cgaffinetranformrotate-atan2-inaccuration/8768448#8768448)

Comment: I wish that I could give this answer 10ooo up votes! In my opinion when you compute an angle using `atan2` (i.e., knowing `delta_x` and `delta_y`) the fraction of abuse of trigonometric functions is close to 95%...